# When I pair with a Bluetooth device using OOB, is the future communication encrypted?

Tags: android, encryption, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

In an Android Nougat app I have written, I use out-of-band (**OOB**) pairing with a Bluetooth Low Energy (**BLE**) device. The device first generates a 16-bit temporary key (**TK**) that is sent to my Android phone through USB, then I make a call to `BluetoothDevice.createBondOutOfBand` through reflection, with this TK.

From that point, I would like to know if all the futures exchanges between my Android phone and the BLE device are encrypted, or not.

Where can I find more details about this?

Thank you!

Comment: AFAIK, if besides *paring* your devices also *bonded*, (both devices have stored the long-term-keys and related info in non-volatile storage), subsequent connections between the two will be secure, and no additional key exchange will be needed. Simply search the web for 'pairing' vs 'bonding'. Here is a nice one for example: https://medium.com/@kbabcockuf/bridging-the-gap-bluetooth-le-security-aab27232a767

Comment: I agree. When bonded (Andoird does not really make a difference between pairing and bonding), encryption is used for all services in future. Even if they do not require it.